# React - Links not updating to new base url after deploying webpage

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So, still learning React, and getting there. I've deployed my react webpage to my online testserver, and it is communicating with my Strapi backend on Heroku. Now, all my links set with `<Link to=>` won't update to the new path, so they are all still pointing to the root, just like with the localhost:3000 setup.

Here's why I have tried so far:

1. I have changed the base in my main html file to `<base href="/directoryname/">`
2. I have changed the Route to like this setup: `<Route path="/directoryname/contact" element={<Contact/>} />`
3. I have changed the "homepage" parameter in package.json to   `"homepage": "http://www.example.com/directoryname",`

I can't figure out why my links are still pointing to "/"? What did I forget?

EDIT:
For others with the same problem: The below post fixed one part of it, using `<BrowserRouter basename="/directoryname">`, and setting base href back to "/". When this got correct, however, all pages except the home went 404 when trying to access directly from URL. I was missing a .htaccess file redirecting * to the html file, and I solved that part by adding a .htaccess in the project root, like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /directoryname/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `basename` on `BrowserRouter`, then keep your `<Routes>` *without* the basename (react router will automatically prepend it to both the routes and the links).

Leave the `<base>` HTML tag in as you have it.

Comment: Thanks, adsy. That kind of worked for access via the main page. However, when manually writing using the direct link to, say, http://www.example.com/directoryname/project/1, it's not found. I had this issue earlier on when developing locally, but that was fixed with  <base href="/"> in the html file. When leaving this to / now, it breaks the site. Is this issue something you are familiar with?

Comment: Thats likely a server side issue. You need to make sure your server is setup for HTML5 push state. I.e., your production server (is it expressjs or something else?) has a wildcard route handler on `/directoryname/*` that always loads `index.html` from disk and returns it to the user no matter what the sub-path is.

Comment: I chose to delete my two previous comments, and merge them into one. :) 
This sounds like a .htaccess thing to me? Or can it be done in the react code? 
I'm using react, and my webhost is one.com, which i believe run on apache. The push state thing is pretty new to me, so I would be grateful to be guided more into the correct direction here, so that I can learn whatever needed to get this to work. That said, I find it strange that we need to do all these things manually in 2023...

Comment: I actually solved it with .htaccess! Slightly modifying my post to reflect this. Thanks for your help adsy.